# div disappearing on margin & width animaton problem - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have coded my div to re size and change margin on click of a div with id = `switch`. But it is disappearing on beginning of animation and reappear on the completion of animation. Ypu can see my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/sWvjC/)**. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 overflow: visible !important;
```

to `#sidebar` and`#switch` won't disappear during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because it is hidden underneath your "viewer". If you can move your switch inside the "viewer" and float it left, set margin-left. Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

During the animation the elements overflow is set to "hidden".
As #switch is visually placed outside #sidebar it disappears. Christopher's solution should override it.
It also would'nt happen if you place #switch inside #viewer